# server side function not getting called by dojo onclick event after javascript function

Tags: javascript, vb.net, dojo

I have been trying to get the client side data that is entered into dojo controls to be captured by server side code and then inserted into a DB. I tried hidden values and calling the function from the javascript but that did not work either. I used the browser debugger and found that the error was occurring because it did not identify the server function. 
I really need to try and get this to work having spent too much time on it:

```
 Protected Function load_data()
    Dim fd As New feeds_DB
    Dim errorMsg As String = String.Empty
    errorMsg = clientName.Value.ToString
    Dim recordsAffected As Integer = fd.insert_tfeed("",errorMsg)
    Return recordsAffected
End Function


 function insertData() {
         var clientProj = dijit.byId("clientName").get("value");
         var clientKey = dijit.byId("clientKey").get("value");
         var gnipUrl = dijit.byId("gnipUrl").get("value");
         var hiddenInput = dijit.byId("clientName").get("value");
         alert("NEW CLIENT DATA ACCEPTED FOR- " + clientProj);
         dijit.byId("clientName").set("value", null);
         return false;
  }

<body class="tundra">
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" selected="true">
<td align="left" class="style1"><input type="submit" 
    id="clientSubmit" onClick="insertData();load_data();" 
      runat="server" class="style2" dojoType="dojox.mobile.Button" value="Submit">
```